# Segmentation Fault at the end of a simple _start that doesn't do anything

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, x86-64, nasm

when I assembly the following assembly code I get the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 8
```

My Makefile is as follows

```
all:
    nasm -f elf64 -o asm.o asm.s
    ld asm.o -o asm
    rm asm.o
```

I don't know what the issue is.

I am running 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: You don't use a syscall to exit your program so when finished executing `mov eax, 8` your program continues to execute whatever happens to be in memory until it eventually faults. To exit your program you can add these instructions `mov eax, 60`  `xor edi, edi` `syscall` . A good source of information on Linux System Calls is [Ryan Chapman's blog](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/)

Comment: Thanks so much, it works like a charm! :D

Comment: What does the `xor edi, edi` part do? It seems to work without it.

Comment: It zeroes out the _EDI_ register (which zeroes extends to the entire 64-bit _RDI_ register). _EDI_ contains the value returned when the program exits.You could have used `mov edi, 0` but it takes more bytes in memory. XOR'ing  a value to itself results in 0.

Comment: Hmm. That's a bit over my head as of now, so I'll just keep it in there :p
Thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A simple assembly code cause a segment fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30456230/a-simple-assembly-code-cause-a-segment-fault)

Answer (score 3):

The CPU execute the program, findd the `mov eax, 8` instruction, executed it... and what now? There are no more instructions in the object file, but nobody told the CPU! It executes whatever is next, probably no valid instruction, which results in a segmentation fault, just like @MichaelPetch said.

The easiest solution IMO is to use a wrapper, which takes care of initializing and cleaning up your program, e.g., GCC. Just put the `mov eax, 8` into the `main` function, which you may be familiar with from C.

Modify the source file as follows:

```
section .text
global main

main:
    mov eax, 8
    ret
```

(`main` is a function, so you need the `ret` instruction to return from it.)

and use the following script:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o asm.o asm.s
gcc asm.o -o asm
rm asm.o
```

Comment: once it will have `.data`  latter will not work. you need `gcc -no-pie t.o -o t`

Comment: An actual invalid instruction would result in SIGILL, not SIGSEGV.  If the .text section ended at the end of a page, and the next page was unmapped, then you'd get a segfault from code fetch, but usually there are some `00` bytes later in the same page after the .text contents you asked for.  `00 00` decodes as `add [rax], al`, which of course segfaults if RAX doesn't hold a valid pointer.

Answer (score 3):

I made this fast example.asm with 64 bits registers

```
section .data

        msg db "Hello world"

section .text

        global _start:

_start:

        call _myfunk

        call _exit


_myfunk:

        mov rax,1
        mov rdi,1
        mov rdx,12
        mov rsi,msg
        syscall
        ret


_exit:

        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi,0
        syscall
```

To compile this assembly code you can use nasm and ld commands

```
nasm -f elf64 example.asm -o example.o  
ld example.o -o example.elf
```

and now run the program ./example.elf

Comment: `ret` after the exit syscall will never be reached.  You can omit it, just like how you don't have a `ret` after `call _exit` because that function call won't ever return.  (So it could be a `jmp` instead...)

Answer (score 0):

I am only started with assembly, but I can help - now it's 4 years old and you may not need it, but maybe others.

In this:

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 8
```

you forgot to stop the program after finishing the code,
so inside the `_start` label, you can add 3 lines, just like below:

*(i don't know why you need 8 in eax reg. so i am moving it to ebx)*

```
section .text
global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 8

    mov ebx, eax
    mov eax, 1   ; this is for system call exit
    int 0x80    ; system call
```

Here the value of ebx will be treated as return value , so you can get the value (8) by typing in your terminal

`echo $?`

good luck :)